# How to get unique constraint names from SQL Server with C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, unique-constraint

I have created a unique constraint in an SQL Server Database using the following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT mytable_unique UNIQUE (uid)
```

How can I get all unique constraint names programmatically with C# SQLConnection object?

Comment: From MSDN you could have done a simple google search [get a list of all constraints Sql Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345522.aspx)

Comment: USE <database_name>;
GO
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) as constraint_name
    ,SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name
    ,OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS table_name
    ,type_desc
    ,create_date
    ,modify_date
    ,is_ms_shipped
    ,is_published
    ,is_schema_published
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT' 
    AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('<schema_name.table_name>');
GO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

query on `information_schema.constraint_column_usage`

```
SELECT  TC.Constraint_Name ,
        CC.Column_Name
FROM    information_schema.table_constraints TC
        INNER JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage CC
            ON TC.Constraint_Name = CC.Constraint_Name
WHERE   TC.constraint_type = 'Unique'
ORDER BY TC.Constraint_Name
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also get these from [sys.key_constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174321.aspx):

```
select name from sys.key_constraints where type = 'UQ'
```